# geocode:all rake task not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-geocoder

I am using Mongoid and geocoder.  I have an embedded document/model that I need to geocode and the rake task geocode:all is not working.  The geocoding works if I save an individual object.

The Location model is embedded in the Account model.  When I run;

```
 rake geocode:all CLASS=Location
```

No errors but it doesn't do anything.
If I run;

```
rake geocode:all CLASS=Account
```

I get this error;

```
rake aborted!  undefined method `not_geocoded' for Account:Class
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you put "geocoded_by :address / before_validation :geocode" in your model?